# How to Print JSTL iteration values in a new line

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, jstl

I have a String like below:

String emps="date1,date2,date3,date4";

My requirement is to print like below on a jsp page using JSTL tags:

```
OutPut Should be:
```

date1

date2

date3

date4

I have used the below code in my jsp:

```
<c:set var="string2" value="${fn:split(emps,',')}" />
<c:forEach items="${string2}" var="emps1">
<td><c:out value="${emps1}"/></td>

</c:forEach>
```

But my code is removing  "," this and printing like below in a single line:

```
date1 date2 date3 date4
```

Could any one give me a solution that ,how to print the date values line by line in a jsp using jstl tags?

thanks

**Update:**

```
<c:when test="${requestScope.size!=0}">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Employee Code</th>

                <th>EmployeeName</th>
                <th>EmployeeDepartment</th>
                <th>AbsentDate</th>
                <th>TotalNOOfAbsentDates</th>
            </tr>


            <c:forEach items="${requestScope.set1}" var="emps">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${emps[0]}" /></td>

                    <td><c:out value="${emps[1]}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${emps[2]}" /></td>

                    <td><c:out value="${emps[4]}" /></td>
                    <c:set var="string2" value="${fn:split(emps[3],',')}" />
                    <c:forEach items="${string2}" var="emps1">
                    <td>
                        <p><c:out value="${emps1}"/></p>

                        </td>

                    </c:forEach>

                    </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

**Note:**
I want to print

this(Iteration) data line by line using  `<td>` tag?

Comment: Why have you used `<td>` tags? Is your `<c:forEach>` inside a `<tr>` tag?

Comment: I want to print the data in a table format so I need to use <td>.so how can i use <c:out value="${emps1}"/><br /> with <td> tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements looks little strange, but if you want to output it with table...

```
<table>
    <c:set var="string2" value="${fn:split(emps,',')}" />
    <c:forEach items="${string2}" var="emps1">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${emps1}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

I hope I got your question correctly

---

**upd:**

Try to run next code:

```
<table>
    <c:set var="sourceString" value="${fn:split('q,w,e,r,t,y',',')}" />
    <c:forEach items="${sourceString}" var="element">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${element}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

It works fine for me (it outputs each letter in new row) and I sure that it would work for you. Check out your html code and try to run this code to be sure, that it works.

---

**upd2:**

Finally your code would look like this:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Employee Code</th>

        <th>EmployeeName</th>
        <th>EmployeeDepartment</th>
        <th>AbsentDate</th>
        <th>TotalNOOfAbsentDates</th>
    </tr>


    <c:forEach items="${requestScope.set1}" var="emps">
        <tr>
            <c:set var="string2" value="${fn:split(emps[3],',')}" />
            <c:forEach items="${string2}" var="emps1">

                <td><c:out value="${emps[0]}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${emps[1]}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${emps[2]}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${emps1}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${emps[4]}" /></td>

            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Your mistake was to mix `<tr>` tags wits `<td>`. This code would generate row for each absent date, is it actually what you want?

---

**upd3:**
If you want to output all this dates in only cell (it looks little ugly), use it:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Employee Code</th>

        <th>EmployeeName</th>
        <th>EmployeeDepartment</th>
        <th>AbsentDate</th>
        <th>TotalNOOfAbsentDates</th>
    </tr>


    <c:forEach items="${requestScope.set1}" var="emps">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${emps[0]}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${emps[1]}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${emps[2]}" /></td>
            <td>
                <c:set var="string2" value="${fn:split(emps[3],',')}" />
                <c:forEach items="${string2}" var="emps1">
                    <p>
                        <c:out value="${emps1}"/>
                    </p>
                </c:forEach>
            </td>
            <td><c:out value="${emps[4]}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: I had updated my question,if i run yor code I'm able to display the iteration values in a single line

Comment: ya your updated one is working ,but my code is not working it is printing the values in a single line

Comment: I think you understand my required output in the above link

Answer (score 2):

I would split the `String` into a `List` outside of your .jsp, then place this `List` into the request.  Depending on your surrounding markup you can use a number of ways to put the items on a new line such as `<br/>`, `<div>` or `<p>`.

**Java**

```
String emps="date1,date2,date3,date4";
List<String> empList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(emps.split(",")));
request.setAttribute("empList", empList);
```

**JSTL**

```
<c:forEach items="${empList}" var="emp">
   <div><c:out value="${emp}"/></div>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I want to print the data in a table format so I need to use <td>.so how can i use <c:out value="${emps1}"/><br /> etc... with <td> tag

Comment: <td>
      <div><c:out value="${emps1}"/></div>
      
      </td> like this it is not working

Comment: @Kumar post the surrounding html

Answer (score 0):

Just like, Kevin Bowersox pointed out, I would use either a `<div>` or `<p>` or `<br />` tag inside the `<TD>`